# use variable for style on ionic

Tags: ionic3

i would like to know if it is possible to use variable, declared in my ts file for styling my ionic components.

I know i can do it by declaring the variables as globals, but as they are not fixed, i have to declare then in my ts file.

Example:
i have this code, witch is working:

```
  <ion-col style=" height: 170px; background: rgb(226, 45, 144)" > {{room.name}}</ion-col>
```

But i want something like:

```
<ion-col style=" height: room.height; background: room.bckg_color" > {{room.name}}</ion-col>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I´ve got the response from the ionic academy. 
    https://ionicacademy.com/community/index.php?/topic/368-use-variable-for-style-on-ionic/&tab=comments#comment-1260

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an account for Ionic Academy, can you share the answer ?

Otherwise, this would be my answer,
this is called "inline style", and it can be defined with something like:

```
<ion-col [style.height.%]="room.height" [style.backgroundColor]="room.bckg_color" > 
   {{room.name}}
</ion-col>
```

Or Ionic 1

```
<ion-col [ngStyle]="{height: room.height, backgroundColor: room.bckg_color}">
   {{room.name}}
</ion-col>
```